# Output of perl debugger to file (Windows)

Tags: perl, debugging

I tried to list all the subroutines of a script with the perl debugger and put the results in an external file. But It didn't work.

My code:

```
perl -d -S myscript.pl > results.txt
```

- `-S` = list all subroutines
- `-d` = debug perl script

Greets,

Comment: `perl -h` says `-S   look for programfile using PATH environment variable`. List all subroutines? Never heard of that switch.

Comment: TLP, they're confusing commands in the debugger with command line switches.

Answer (score 2):

In your home directory, create a file called .perldb with the following contents:

`parse_options("NonStop=1 LineInfo=results.txt AutoTrace=1 frame=2");`

And then run the command

`perl -d myscript.pl`

If you want to scan and list the entire subroutine's what Perl see's before it runs:

`perl -MO=Deparse -f myscript.pl`

Answer (score 1):

The -S isn't supposed to be used as a command line switch. Running `perl -d` will start a debugger process, and one of the commands you can use there is `S`.

Example:

```
$ perl -d tmp/splithttpdconf.pl 

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.28
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(tmp/splithttpdconf.pl:6):        my $basedir = shift;

DB<1> S main::
main::BEGIN
main::debug
main::splitconf

DB<2>
```

In order to get the kind of output you want, you can to use the profiler module Devel::DProf instead. It'll output profiler info into a file which can be read by the dprofpp program. Here's an example to get the list of subroutines:

```
perl -d:DProf perlscript.pl; dprofpp -T
```

If you only want the subroutines within your own script, and not those loaded from other modules, add a grep to it, e.g.:

```
perl -d:DProf perlscript.pl; dprofpp -T | grep main::
```

Though for the particular question of knowing what subroutines exist in a given program, provided you use a consistent coding style it'd probably be easier to just do a `grep "sub.*{"` to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the answers,

My problem is that I want to execute a perl debugger command
and directly get the result to in output file in one command.
In your example I will have to execute two seperate commands and 
I cant get the result to an output file.

Greets,

Comment: OK, you need to use another perl module to do that. I'll add the info.

Comment: Thanks it worked! 
But isn't there a way to apply this to every command of the perl debugger?
Greets,

Comment: There's not a straight one-to-one match between the debugger commands and Devel::DProf. You need to read the documentation for Devel::DProf to find out how to do what you want.